# Forcing a script to run in english

Tags: terminal, script, kindle

My Mac is running Mavericks in English, but because my region is set to Portugal  and my keyboard is the portuguese one, when I run some scripts they shows messages in portuguese. I generally hate to run software created by non-native people in Portuguese because the translation is always crappy. I end with messages like "cubra is not defined". What the hell is a "cubra"?

So, these scripts are reading something from the system and switching to portuguese. Is there a way to force them to always run in english?

My terminal has this option selected:

```
Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced > Set locale environment variables on startup
```

Comment: Do you have some environment variables set to something like pt_BR ?

Comment: how do I know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the program. If it uses `gettext` which is a common library for doing internationalization then setting the `LANG` environment variable to `en_US` (or `en_UK` if you want British Enligh vs. American English) should do the trick.

If you *only* want specific applications to use english messages then you can alias the command to something like `LANG=en_US command-you-want-in-english`.

Aliasing is dependant upon which shell you are using but in `bash` (the default shell on MacOSX) you would put the following command in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
alias command='LANG=en_US command'
```

When in doubt - look to the man page or manual for the command you are running to see if they give details on how their internationalization is implemented and how you as a user can control it.

Comment: Sorry, you were typing your answer at the same time I was changing the question to be generic, when I realized that on kindlegen. Anyway I have this problem with other scripts, so I transformed the question into a generic one. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then I think you want the LANG environment variable - but it depends upon the program - if it pays attention to that variable. I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't unchecked "Set locale environment variables on startup", Terminal sets `LANG` based on the region selected in System Preferences.

```
$ defaults read -g AppleLocale
ja_JP
$ locale
LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ asd
bash: asd: コマンドが見つかりません
```

You can change `LANG` by adding a line like this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

After that the commands above should print something like this:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ asd
bash: asd: command not found
```

`LC_ALL` does not have to be set. `LANG` and `LC_ALL` are different ways to change the the actual `LC_` variables that are shown between `LANG` and `LC_ALL` above. `LANG` is used as a default value for unset locale variables. `LC_ALL` overrides locale variables even if they have been set, and if it is set, changing other locale variables has no effect.

If you uncheck "Set locale environment variables on startup" and don't configure the locale variables anywhere, shells will use the C locale by default. It makes working with non-ASCII text difficult though. In bash non-ASCII characters are displayed and inserted as escape-sequences and for example `ä` is interpreted as `M-l`. You can fix all those by [changing output-meta, input-meta, and convert-meta in ~/.inputrc](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC12), but even then `pbpaste` and `pbcopy` jumble up UTF-8 characters, `ls` shows non-ASCII characters as question marks, and you can't type non-ASCII characters in Emacs. It's easier to use a UTF-8 locale in my opinion.